# BrowserSync not working when on LTE connection or no Internet Connection

Tags: apache, gulp, virtualhost, browser-sync

My local dev environment (MBP) has apache running with a dynamic virtual host which allows me to have any project accessible via a consistent url structure:
http://[client_name].[project_name].localhost

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/mbp/repos/%1/websites/%2/public_html"
  ServerName sites.localhost
  ServerAlias *.*.localhost
  UseCanonicalName Off
  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</Virtualhost>
```

my `package.json` file includes a `client` and `site` key/value which is then imported into my gulpfile and makes these values accessible via `pkg.client` & `pkg.site`.

```
const { default: pkg } = await import("./package.json", {
  assert: {
    type: "json",
  },
});
```

My gulpfile.js inits browserSync

```
  browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    proxy: pkg.client + '.' + pkg.site + '.localhost'
  });
```

When I run gulp, it opens a new browser window to http://localhost:3000

If i'm on a wifi connection, this works flawlessly.
If i'm on a tethered LTE connection (Mobile Data), it will not load.
If i turn off wifi and have no internet connection, it will not load.

I've tried browsersync option `online`

- https://browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-online

To further clarify, this is all being accessed from the same machine. I'm not trying to connect to a browsersync session from a separate device.

Has anyone encountered this and have a fix?

Comment: _"If i'm on a tethered LTE connection (Mobile Data), it will not load."_ - You seem to _expect it to work_ - but please think about _how it could possibly work_ considering it means that your computer is no-longer on the same network as your phone... (i.e. it won't work) - at least not until and unless you either get IPv6 working end-to-end - but as a stopgap you could run your own VPN tunnel back into your desktop's LAN...

Comment: My dev machine is my laptop which is just getting internet via wifi or LTE - both IPv4. Gulp / Browsersync is still running on the laptop with the browser trying to load localhost:3000

Comment: If I turn off my wifi connection, localhost:3000 will not load but if I access my virtualhost http://client_name.project_name.localhost it loads fine.